# Sync my files across multiple computers

Tags: file-sharing, version-control, cross-platform, online-storage

I do a lot of work on my home computer, ranging from programming, writing stored procedures and writing documentation and reporting. A lot of this work is university related and constantly swapping files across several computers is annoying at best.

I have a large final-year project coming up and I'm going to be sharing this work amongst home and university and require some kind of online storage that provides version control for my programs, as well as my Word documents, PDF's and saved academic papers.

Are there any good solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 11):

[Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) would be my first pick. Free too. I've had very good results using this as a sort of portable storage from home to work to other places.

Comment: +1 for Dropbox.  I'm totally amazed at how much I use it.

Comment: It's not the first, but it's among them and has kept good service since then. It's the best free service you can have. As a curiosity, it was a startup by YCombinator.

Answer (score 3):

What OS are you running?

Like Josh K, Dropbox would be my first choice. However, if you're a windows guy you might also look at [Live Mesh](https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx) (beta) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing for homework as well as writing books.  Check out Live Mesh (https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx)