# What software to use to keep important files mirrored on several PCs / Mac?

Tags: file-management, mirroring, sync

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Any software to do minute by minute backup ?](https://superuser.com/questions/144402/any-software-to-do-minute-by-minute-backup)
>   [Sync my files across multiple computers](https://superuser.com/questions/52500/sync-my-files-across-multiple-computers)
>   [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)

There are sometimes important files that we don't want to lose and be able to access it on all different PCs and Macs at home.  If they are text files for constant editing, then the Source Code Versioning Systems such as CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial should be good tools for mirroring the files and keeping the revisions.

But what if the file are PDF, mp3, .doc, .xls, .avi -- binary type of files instead of ASCII text files.  In this case, what is a good method / software for achieving this purpose?

Comment: Given your *"important files that we don't want to lose"* you're actually referring to versioning or backing up files, not to mirroring (as otherwise any erroneous change or deletion would propagate to all mirrored instances as well). As such, there are *many* questions here on Super User that somehow handle the question. Unless you can add some more very specific requirements, I am voting to close as a duplicate of, for example, [Any software to do minute by minute backup?](http://superuser.com/questions/144402/any-software-to-do-minute-by-minute-backup)

Comment: ah, or the software will ask, "You are deleting from this 'Sync' folder, are you sure you want to delete in all the other computers as well?"

Comment: Given the many prompts a computer user gets: how to ensure you won't select "Yes" when actually you mean "No"? (Or only realize some time later that you should have selected "No"?) And then still, for edits: how would the software know when to prompt you whether or not the changes should be propagated to the mirrors? Anyway, mirroring has been covered many times as well, like in [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync). I'd vote to keep the answers in one place rather than having many similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) is the usual answer for something like like. It's cross platform and free.

Answer (score 0):

I like [SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com). It's basically Dropbox but it offers 5GB instead of 2GB from Dropbox.

Comment: If you need even more space, live sync is good too.

Comment: is SkyDrive limited to the 25GB of data that you have to put online as well? Can it simply mirror or sync your local PCs and Mac's hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said "at home", look at [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) -- syncs directly, computer to computer, over your LAN, without storing your files on anyone else's server.  Free and cross platform, too.